# Automated Push time event using Postman

Tags: postman, oracle-fusion-apps

I tried using Postman with the payload provided by Oracle, which was successfully uploaded. However, when I attempted to attach these CSV and JSON files in the body as form-data, I was unable to load them in Postman.

I also saved the above files in my Postman directory location.

How can I load bulk data through a file while scheduling the API?

Rest API: `/hcmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/timeEventRequests`

Payload:

```json
{
         "requestNumber": "{{Id}}",
         "sourceId": "HQ-Office",
         "requestTimestamp": "{{currentTimestamp}}",
         "timeEvents": [
            {
               "eventDateTime": "{{EventTime}}",
               "supplierDeviceEvent": "{{Location}}",
               "reporterId": "{{CardHolderId}}",
               "reporterIdType": "PERSON",
               "timeEventAttributes": [
                  {
                     "name": "PayrollTimeType",
                     "value": "Regular Shift Hours"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
}
```

CSV File:

```
Id,CardHolderId,EventTime,Location
456eer678qwertabc123,3370,2023-05-29T19:20:00.000+00:00,HQ-Office TURNSTILE 1 (IN)
456eer678qwertabc124,3370,2023-05-29T21:20:00.000+00:00,HQ-Office TURNSTILE 3 (OUT)
456eer678qwertabc125,3370,2023-05-29T22:00:00.000+00:00,HQ-Office TURNSTILE 2 (IN)
456eer678qwertabc126,3370,2023-05-30T00:57:00.000+00:00,HQ-Office TURNSTILE 2 (OUT)
```

I want to add file in form data along with payload so that when file got replaced with same name in the directory location then automatically postman will pick and load data

I am trying to make automated with scheduling collection for every week.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that API (I think it's this one - https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/human-resources/23b/farws/op-timeeventrequests-post.html) but it looks more like it should be a JSON payload and should be placed in `Body > raw > JSON` - It contains Postman variables `{{...}}` that are resolved by the values in the CSV file.

[image]

The `currentTimestamp` is missing from the CSV file though so you would need to handle that, depending on the format `{{$timestamp}}` or `{{$isoTimestamp}}` might work.

When in the Scheduled Run setup, you can use the *Data file* option to select the CSV file from your local file explorer before creating the job.

[image]

Comment: This is already done. But I want to schedule and fix my file location in the system so that Postman will automatically pick and load data.  In form-data we can define our file but not working

Comment: Suppose I want to upload new data then we have to open again postman and attach a file in the run collection this makes it a manual process. Any automated process so that I can just replace file data with the the same file name?

Comment: If you wanted a level of control and flexibility to what you're doing, you can use Newman to create a script that will allow you to do the things you need and run that via a CI/CD tool on any schedule you want. Scheduled Runs wouldn't give you that flexibility.

Comment: Can you help me with the script if possible?